# GraphQL with Prisma: how to make a delete mutation

Tags: graphql, prisma, graphql-codegen

I am trying to figure out how to make a delete mutation in my app.

I have an Issue Service, Issue Resolver, and Issue Form.

The service has:

```
import { prisma } from "../../lib/prisma"
import { Service } from "typedi"
import { IssueInput } from "./inputs/create.input"
import { Resolver } from "type-graphql"
import { Issue } from "./issue.model"

@Service()
@Resolver(() => Issue)
export class IssueService {
  async createIssue(data: IssueInput) {
    return await prisma.issue.create({ data })
  }

  async getAllIssues() {
    return await prisma.issue.findMany()
  }
 
 

  async getIssue(id: string) {
    return await prisma.issue.findUnique({ where: { id } })
  }

  async deleteIssue(id: string) {
    return await prisma.issue.delete({ where: { id } })
  }
}
```

The resolver has:

```
import { Arg, Mutation, Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql"
import { Issue } from "./issue.model"
import { IssueService } from "./issue.service"
import { IssueInput } from "./inputs/create.input"
import { Inject, Service } from "typedi"

@Service()
@Resolver(() => Issue)
export default class IssueResolver {
  @Inject(() => IssueService)
  issueService: IssueService

  @Query(() => [Issue])
  async allIssues() {
    return await this.issueService.getAllIssues()
  }

 


  @Query(() => Issue)
  async issue(@Arg("id") id: string) {
    return await this.issueService.getIssue(id)
  }

  @Mutation(() => Issue)
  async createIssue(@Arg("data") data: IssueInput) {
    return await this.issueService.createIssue(data)
  }

  @Mutation(() => Issue)
  async deleteIssue(@Arg("id") id: string)  {
    return await this.issueService.deleteIssue(id)
  }
}
```

My lib/graphql sort of recognises that I tried to make the mutations. It has entries as follows:

```
export type Mutation = {
  __typename?: 'Mutation';
  createIssue: Issue;
  deleteIssue: Issue;

export type MutationDeleteIssueArgs = {
  id: Scalars['String'];
};
```

Apart from the above two references, the lib/graphql does not have something that looks like the other mutations and queries.

In the issue form, I want to try and use the delete mutation, so I tried:

```
import {
  IssueInput,
  useAllIssuesQuery,
  useCreateIssueMutation,
  useDeleteIssueMutation, ## this is not recognised as an exported member of lib/graphql
  
} from "lib/graphql"
```

How can I add it to the lib/graphql. Whatever the process for generating the mutation was has obviously run, but I don't understand why it didn't make something I can use in the form.

My goal is to try and figure out how to write something along the following lines to try and delete an entry.

```
 { onDelete: async (id) => {
         await fetch("api/issue", { method: "delete" }),
           toast({
             title: "Issue deleted",
            
           })
         refetch()
       refetchClimate()
       }
       }
```